# D3js button onclick function to zoom the graph for specific timeframe

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

**Expectation**

the initial graph showed the full data of csv and the expected output is when i clicked on the button below the x-axis, let's say i click on the '1 hour' button, then the graph will rescale according to data for the first 1 hour, same goes for other buttons.

**Problem**

The current problem is when i clicked on the button, the graph will rescale to middle position(random data) instead of specific position( specific data, exp( first 1 hour, 3 hours, and etc) that stated on the button. Here is the code for me click on the button to zoom the graph to specific timeframe.

```
   function transition(zoomLevel) {
      svg.transition()
          .call(zoom.scaleTo, zoomLevel);
    }

    function timezoom(){

     x.domain([new Date(2017,1,11),new Date(2017,1,11)]).range([0,60]);
     y.domain([95000,d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.AGV_Mileage; })]);
     x2.domain(x.domain());
     y2.domain(y.domain());

     var svg = d3.select("body").transition();
     //
    }


    <input type="button"  id='1hr' onclick="timezoom()" value="1 Hour" />
   <input type="button"  id='3hr' onclick="transition(1.8)" value="3 Hours"/>
```

The zoom's behavior is demonstrated in the plunker editor - https://plnkr.co/edit/MY1nP4Mnv4WeCpHCxLvD?p=preview

Please enlighten me and give me a rough idea on this.

Comment: What is the issue? What do you mean by "I can only zoom the graph randomly but not to the range of specific value"? The plnkr seems to be working fine.

Comment: sorry for didn't make my question clear enough, the initial graph showed the full data of csv, but the expected output is when i click on the button below the x-axis, let's say i click on the '1 hour' button, then the graph will rescale to the data for the first 1 hour, same goes to other buttons. The current problem is when i click on the button, the graph will rescale to random position instead of specified position that stated on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the `translate` as well the `scale` on the `transform` call.

```
function transition(newRange) {
  var rgh = d3.timeHour.count(initialDomain[0], initialDomain[1]);
  var k = rgh/newRange;
  var t = d3.zoomIdentity.translate(0,0).scale(k);
  svg.transition()
      .call(zoom.transform, t);
}
```

You should also save the initial domain in order to calculate the new scale:

```
  initialDomain = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Timestamp; });
```

Here is the updated [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/okXVOgQxWOLlwpZmLEzI?p=preview)

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but i'm not really understand the first two lines of code (var rgh and k), do you mind to explain it?

Comment: We are trying to find the scale factor `k` to apply to transform. `rgh` is the original range is hours. We find `k` dividing  `rgh` by `newRange`. BTW: There is a bug in the code. `d3.timeHour.count` results on integer hours. That is why on the example, the new range is not exactly 1 hour when you press 1h button. `rgh` is calculated as 5 instead of 5.xx.